# css 'frame-like' nav menu's layout breaks on window resize

Tags: html, css

If you click here: http://www.ideagasms.net/index2 you'll see the nav menu surrounds the banner image, like a frame. It was put together that way using three div's, two of which are css rotate 90 deg, position absolute. Of course, as soon as you resize the window the navmenu breaks.

There must be a better way to build a frame-like menu. A couple suggestions, or examples, I just need ideas on how to build something like this. Maybe a jquery solution or something would do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change `#nav-left` and `#nav-right` positions to absolute, then center them with `left: 50%` (like you did with `#headerwrapper`), and correct their positions with margins, for example `margin: 0 auto 20px 122px` for `#nav-right`.

Answer (score 0):

Mark their parent element with `position: relative;` (but without any `top/left/bottom/right` propertes), that way the rotated navigation elements will be positioned within their parent rather than the window.

However, I think your navigation concept is novel, but terrible (and also visually unappealing) from a usability perspective because people can't read rotated English text easily.